# Android: Support all devices above min sdk version but also restrict to specific devices under min sdk version

Tags: android, android-manifest, google-play, android-market-filtering

Is there a way to filter your app's visibility on the play store by both [the device availability dialog](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/1286017?hl=en) OR a [min framework version](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html)?  For example, I would like the app to be available to all devices running Android 4.0 or higher, but if the device is running anything less than 4.0, I'd like to limit availability to specific devices.

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what are your limits below 4.0?

Comment: You can filter out devices individually on the dev console

Comment: @MorrisonChang: Unfortunately no, I have specific requirements from my client which I can't elaborate here.

Comment: @jcw: Correct, but it doesn't seem like I can specify both parameters. It's either limit to specific devices (regardless of sdk version) or I can set a min sdk in my manifest. I need the limit on specific devices only under a min sdk, but I can leave it open to all devices on 4.0 and above.

Comment: so what you should do is to set in your manifest to all devices above a certain sdk level (the lowest that you want to allow) and then in the dev console, select all the devices which you want to exclude.

Comment: It seems like that approach would lead to a constant game of monitoring the console for new devices that I need to exclude. Also, since the console doesn't list sdk versions associated to a device, I'd need to look that up elsewhere.  I'd also end up excluding a device that may have been upgraded to 4.0 at a later time.

Comment: @ZeBT - so nothing shown here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html can be used to qualify the devices you want to limit to?

Comment: @MorrisonChang: That is correct. For my need, I can not limit devices appropriately based on the feature tags listed on that page.